# Qt Show/Hide Widget not smooth

Tags: c++, qt

I have encountered the following issue:

When I double click one of the `QGLWidget`s, what I want to do is to expand that clicked widget to full parent widget size, and if the full size widget is double cliked again, it restores back to show all widgets, so the code is like this:

`display_widgets_` stores all created `QGLWidget`s.

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick)
    {
        QMouseEvent* mouseEv = (QMouseEvent*)event;
        if(mouseEv->buttons() == Qt::LeftButton)
        {
            display_widgets_[0]->parentWidget()->setUpdatesEnabled(false);
            if(!showAll_){
                for(auto& it:display_widgets_)
                {
                    it->show();
                }
                showAll_ = true;
            }else{
                for(auto& it: display_widgets_)
                {
                    if(watched == it)
                    {
                        selected_widget_ = it;
                        showAll_ = false;
                        selected_widget_->show();
                    }else
                    {
                        it->hide();
                    }
                }
            }
            display_widgets_[0]->parentWidget()->setUpdatesEnabled(true);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(watched, event);
}
```

**BUT**, in the process of `Double Click`, I got this effect:

[image]

And it will finally resize to normal size, but I always got this ugly transformation.

More Information:
I subclassed the `QGLWidget` to create my own `QGLWidget` so that I can move each `QGLWidget` context to a thread to fast rendering.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several trial and error, I changed the `QGLWidget` to `QOpenGLWidget` and this ugly effect disappeared. My Qt Version is 5.8-msvc2015. This problem only occurs when using `QGLWidget`.